# Recursion theory in $\sf HC$

Tags: set-theory, computability

Let $\sf HF$ be the set of hereditarily finite sets. It is well known that one can define a theory of computable/recursive functions on $\sf HF$ (as opposed to working with $\omega^k$): a relation $R\subseteq \sf HF^n$ is *decidable* iff $R$ is a $\Delta_1$ subset of $(\sf HF,\in)$, and a function $f:\sf HF^n\to \sf HF$ is *computable* iff it is decidable as a subset of $\sf HF^{n+1}$.

By work of Ackermann, this approach turns out to be equivalent to the usual one, in the sense that one has a (computable) bijection $\Gamma:\sf HF\to \omega$ which can be used to translate between the two notions of computable and see that they are morally the same.

The usual selling point of working with $\sf HF$ is that no coding is necessary, for $\sf HF\times \sf HF\subset \sf HF$ and similarly $\sf HF^{<\omega}\subset \sf HF$.

Can this be reproduced at $\sf HC$, the set of hereditarly countable sets, i.e. get an alternative definition of the projective hierarchy of sets of reals? Two of the problems I see are:

1. Every set in $\sf HC$ can be coded by a real, but the coding is slightly arbitrary (as opposed to the Ackermann function), since we need to say "fix $x\in \sf HC$, and let $f:\omega\to \text{trcl}(\{x\})$ be a bijection (ignore the finite case), transfer the $\in$-relation on $\text{trcl}(\{x\})$ to $\omega$, take the collapse, etc".
2. A set of reals $A$ is $\underset{\sim}{\Sigma}_2^1$ iff it is $\Sigma_1$ definable over $\sf HC$.

So (2) shows that levels of definability are not directly comparable as they are in the $\sf HF$ case, presumably because everything in $\sf HF$ is $\Delta_0$ definable, but no such thing is true of $\sf HC$.

Is there any way of making a theory of computability over $\sf HC$ work, or are things doomed from the get go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the big problems is that $\mathsf{HC}$, unlike $\mathsf{HF}$, is **rather underspecified** by the usual axioms of set theory.

For example, one possibility is that $\mathsf{HC}=L_{\omega_1}$. Admissible levels of the $L$-hierarchy support a very good analogue of computability theory, namely **$\alpha$-recursion theory**. Sacks' book [*Higher recursion theory*](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/perspectives-in-logic/Higher-Recursion-Theory/toc/pl/1235422631) has a wealth of information on the topic; in particular, most standard priority arguments go through pretty effortlessly in $L_{\omega_1}$ *(although there are exceptions, e.g. the existence of maximal c.e. sets)*. On the other hand, if for example we have large cardinals in our universe then $\mathsf{HC}$ lacks any simply-definable well-ordering, and this stands in the way of any sort of argument which would involve enumerating Turing machines.

I think it's helpful to identify four types of "computability on a transitive set" $T$:

- In admissible recursion theory, we assume $T\models\mathsf{KP}$ (= Kripke-Platek set theory). In such a $T$ we have a natural notion of "finite" (= "element of $T$") and "c.e." (= "$\Sigma_1(T)$") which behave not too badly; however, we don't generally have a simple well-ordering of the universe so we can't perform searches or set up priority arguments.
- In $\alpha$-recursion theory, $T=L_\alpha$ for some admissible ordinal $\alpha$. This improves on the previous bulletpoint, and $\alpha$-recursion generalizes classical computability theory rather well.
- In $\beta$-recursion theory, $T=L_\beta$ for some **non-admissible** ordinal $\beta$. This is the dual situation to admissible recursion theory: we completely sacrifice replacement but require full "search capability." At this point the notion of finiteness becomes rather more nuanced; see Maass' paper, [*Recursively invariant $\beta$-recursion theory*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003484381900152).
- In principle we could keep going and look at transitive sets satisfying very weak set theories. Certainly there is work on such topics (see e.g. [various papers of Mathias](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/%7Eardm/scdlistC.html)); however, my opinion is that in the absence of *both* replacement and searchability there isn't much computability-theoretic character left.

Comment: I was hoping you'd chime in :P So, say, a measurable cardinal obliterates any hope of developing such a thing, by killing any $\Sigma_2^1$ well-ordering of the reals? I think at some point I opened Sacks' book (or maybe it was his Model Theory book), but recoiled in horror at his conventions for quantifiers. I shall give it another try. And I'll check the other sources you cited, thanks :)

Comment: @Reveillark So this is an ongoing interest of mine! I think the most immediate takeaway is "It depends what we want our computability theory to do." I have various rambling thoughts on the matter, and I might add to this answer if I can get any of them to gel later. Separately you may enjoy reading the introduction to Simpson/Weitkamp's [*High and low Kleene degrees of coanalytic sets*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2273552).